# .htaccess file in magento contains what?

Tags: .htaccess

I have my .htaccess contains the following:

```
Mac OS X 2¢ÔATTRÔ˜<˜<com.apple.quarantineq/0002;5596b949;Safari;F9417E7F-EAFC-41E0-BA60-E4E5FB339DEA
```

I don't know if this file is should be like that or is currently something wrong with it? Please advice thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your .htaccess file for Magento should not look like that.  You may have a default OSX file or something in the folder.

I would recommend looking at this sample .hataccess file from Creare.
https://github.com/Creare/magento-htaccess/blob/master/.htaccess
It is an optimized version of the default Magento file, but enhanced for speed and SEO.

Keep in mind that .htaccess files like this are just a sample starting point.  Certain option may need to be adjusted or commented out for your particular website or web host

Comment: Can we stay in contact as i will need some help with this. I am new in magento and some of the files need to be checked. The reason why im asking this, cause some of the pages not found 404, so i turned the SEO off from admin panel. But I know is recommended to leave it on! Thank you once again.

Comment: I would be happy to help and share what I can.  you can reach me on twitter @the80y

Answer (score 0):

as of my knowledge the file should not have that if it is in magento it should have that line the .htaccess file in the root magento should have about 250 lines of code giving access and diny to most of files and folders in magento.

You must look into this document for more information about .htaccess.

https://www.whoishostingthis.com/resources/htaccess/

Comment: Thank you I am learning about the commenting and answering rules as I spend time in this website.